# SVG – animate rectangle along path; center of rect always on the path

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I wanted to animate a rectangle so that it follows a given path which worked thus far using `animateMotion`. This is what I have got:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<g>
   <rect height="40" width="40" style="fill:#777; stroke:none;"/>
   <animateMotion fill="freeze" path="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" dur="3.14159s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</g>
<path d="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" style="fill:none;stroke:#F00;stroke-width:5"/>
```

Now my question: How do I get the rectangle to follow the path (already achieved) with the center of the rectangle (`20 20`) always being on the path? Can this be achieved with the means SVG offers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just add a transform to the rect.

```css
html, body, svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g>
       <rect transform="translate(-20,-20)" height="40" width="40" style="fill:#777; stroke:none;"/>
       <animateMotion fill="freeze" path="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" dur="3.14159s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
    <path d="M 0 0 Q 190 160 150 70 T 200 150 T 300 200 T 200 200" style="fill:none;stroke:#F00;stroke-width:5"/>
</svg>
```

The translate acts to move the rect origin from 0,0 to the rectangle centre.

Comment: How cool would your answer be, if you would just add a link to an active fiddle with your working solution.

Comment: It worked, thank you. But why? I know what the `translate` part usually does but do not understand why it works in this case and does what I intended to do.

Comment: @RobertLongson how so? Your reply seems to make a point, that you've received feedback suggesting not to add fiddle links, is that right? Sound rather bizarre if that's the case...

Comment: @MorganWilde it's now a stack snippet so it will run here.